# Improve the NAA/VLQ flagging mechanism

Tags: discussion, feature-request, answers, flags

Currently, while one stumbles upon a NAA (Not An Answer), or VLQ (Very Low Quality) post, they can flag it accordingly.

The problem is these flags cover a broad spectrum of answers, ranging from obvious ones:

- answers not even remotely related to the problem
- link-only answers
- answers that are in fact other questions, sometimes related to the current question
- answers added by the asker that should've instead been edits to the question

, to more subtle ones, like:

- answers only tangential to the problem
- answers given in other similar programming languages

While the first category of problematic posts are easy to detect, the second one might pose some difficulties, and this is one of the reasons we get many NAA/VLQ flags declined due to technical reasons.

However, the problem I want to raise is that the burden of categorizing the NAA/VLQ flag falls on the shoulders of the reviewers, since the flagger has no other options than flagging as NAA/VLQ. So the flag reviewer is the one that needs to pick a category.

I propose improving the UX of the flagging feature by allowing flaggers to also specify why they think the answer falls into one of the NAA/VLQ categories. Similar as with the close reasons, we could have a list of choices for the user to choose from, so that reviewers can easily agree or not with the flag.

Comment: *"answers not even remotely related to the problem"* is a wrong answer, not not an answer.

Comment: *link-only answers* Also an answer. An incomplete, weak answer.

Comment: [The grand canonical for dealing with NAA](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer)

Comment: "*the flagger has no other options than flagging as NAA*" Wrong! Please use custom mod flag to describe things that should be deleted but are not obvious NAA

Comment: @kevin, well if I'm asking about airplanes, and you answer describing trains, does that make your post an "answer"?

Comment: Yes, it is an answer to another question.

Comment: If the answer should be deleted because it doesn't answer the question or is written in the wrong language, please use a custom flag and clearly explain that. Mods should not be expected to evaluate the correctness of each answer when handling NAA flags. If an answer looks like an answer then such flag will be declined

Comment: @Dharman does this mean that we don't need other flags at all, and we should just flag all answers for mod attention?

Comment: The purpose of NAA is to collect all of the low hanging fruit into one easily digestible basket of posts for mod review. Mods shouldn't be expected to evaluate each and every one of them for correctness, that defeats the purpose. Putting all of the posts with the same problem into the same list makes processing the list more efficient.

Comment: The point I'm trying to make is that we can just flag as NAA, however the reviewer doesn't know why I flagged as NAA, sometimes it's obvious, however sometimes is not

Comment: @Cristik mods aren't SMEs in *everything*. If you flag a question as NAA because, to you, it's clearly wrong doesn't mean that the mod that handles the flag can see that as easily; especially in a subject they have no experience in.

Comment: @Cristik All flags are for mod attention. The only difference is whether the reason is a standard reason or needs a little bit of an explanation.

Comment: I mean, i could see adding the reasons that are wrong as honeypot options that instead suggest the flagger downvote

Comment: @Dharman so why not make mods and flag reviewers life easier? If one flags as NAA, I assume they have a pretty good idea why the answer is bad. With the current implementation, others are left to guess why the answer was flagged in the first place.

Comment: This applies to both NAA and VLQ - the other flag reason are pretty clear.

Comment: @Cristik If you are talking about LQA review then you should handle it similar to how mods handle it. If it's unclear why the post landed in the review then decline/mark as looks ok.

Comment: @user4581301 Um, what? Link-only answers are **not** answers. There has to be enough context for the answer to be useful even without the link, at which point it's no longer link-only by our definition. The answer you linked to even explicitly says "**Notice that this is not necessarily the same thing as a "link-only answer"** (although there is much overlap)." - there are exceptions where only a link is fine, but that's "where the link itself is the answer to the question are excluded and should not be flagged"

Comment: It's that darned interpretation again. NAA. What is that? Not An Answer? Not an Attempt to Answer? The latter is true, but then it is still ambiguous. Not an Attempt to Answer... THIS question? ANY question? Currently ANY question keeps being the victor... not because it is efficient (quite the contrary), but because there is a big hesitation to allow people to use the flag to just make whatever they don't like the look of to go up in smoke as soon as possible.

Answer (score 16):

If it's not obvious why the flagger used NAA, then it means they used the wrong type of flag. NAA flags means "this is obviously not an answer, no matter how one might look at it". This means that NAA can be safely used for things such as:

- another question posted as an answer
- an upvote posted as an answer in the form of "thank you, it worked"
- weird gibberish that doesn't convey any meaningul information (please don't flag regex answers)
- a picture of an answer
- a link to an answer
- a picture of a unicorn
- etc.

These are clearly not solutions to any problem and cannot be considered an answer. No need to explain why you flagged as NAA.

For all the things where it's not so obvious why the post needs to be deleted, please use other flag types. Usually, this means that you need to write the reason yourself in the available flag box. Mods will then be able to understand why you consider this post to be not an answer that should be deleted.

Very low quality flags should generally be avoided. They are reserved for things that you can't make heads or tails out of, but it looks like it was an attempted answer. Unless someone can edit it into shape, including the author, then the post should be deleted by mods. An answer in a language other than English is a good example, because it might be an answer, but the explanation is unclear unless you speak that language. It might also be a new question... It should be deleted.

Comment: While I agree with this, the current implementation still doubles the cognitive load needed when processing a bad post, and what's worse it forces reviewers attempting at guesses when the flags are correct, but the NAA/VLQ reason is not that obvious.

Comment: @Cristik Reviewers should not guess. If they can't clearly see why it is not an answer, then the flag will be declined.

Comment: The flagging UX works by the reviewer having to choose the proper deletion reason, which most of the time carries a useful comment for the OP, while the question close-reasons carry this helpful information by default. I was proposing to do something similar for flags.

Comment: If you want to inform the author, feel free to leave a comment, whether you are the flagger or the reviewer. However, the reviewer shouldn't need to see your comment to make the decision.

Comment: One important note: **LQA review contains posts that have not been flagged by anyone**. Do not assume that every post you see when reviewing that queue was flagged by someone.